# How to show different values if entry is empty

Tags: php, sql

I am using PHP and SQL. I want to achieve what can be pseudo-coded as:

```
if the field 'pro_foto1' is not empty:
  show the value of the field 'pro_foto1'
else:
  if the field 'pro_thema' is 'Vrede en Mensenrechten':
    show '/afbeeldingen/vrede-en-mensenrechten.jpg'
  if the field 'pro_thema' is 'Samenleven in Nederland'
    show '/afbeeldingen/samenleven-in-nederland.jpg'
  and so on
```

What PHP code could allow me to do that? My main difficulty resides in the detection of empty fields.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and add an appropriate database tag for the database you are using.

Comment: You dismissed the coalesce answer without even trying it. Thus, I'm dismissing this question and not bothering to answer it.

Comment: I have tried to find how I can work with coalesce ... see comment under the coalesce answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want `coalesce()` in your SQL query?

```
select coalesce(pro_foto1, pro_thema) as what_I_show
```

I cannot quite tell what is in the columns, you might want to construct the `pro_thema` return value:

```
select coalesce(pro_foto1,
                concat('/afbeeldingen/', replace(lower(pro_thema), ' ', '-'),
               ) as what_I_show
```

Comment: I am not sure how to put this into my php-file. I tried the following `code` global $wpdb;
$photo = $wpdb->get_results("select coalesce(pro_foto1,
                concat('/afbeeldingen/', replace(lower(pro_thema), ' ', '-'),
               ) as what_I_show");`code`. There should be a .jpg after the name of the photo. Also if there is an entry in the field pro_foto1, this will be "/afbeeldingen/name-of-field-pro_foto1"

Comment: @Ullitasch . . . Your question is tagged "sql" implying that you are using a query.  If you are not, then remove the tag and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for answering. I am working with SQL database and I request for information from a database. So I think I am using a query, right? I don't need the "first non-null value in a list" but an option if this field is empty, then print something else (depending on value of another field: pro_thema)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, using wordpress, you can read your row of data into an associative array `$row`, and then process it using something like this:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM haella_projecten_test WHERE pro_status = 'normaal'",
                              "ARRAY");
foreach ($results as $row) {
    if (!empty($row['pro_foto1'])) {
        $photo = $row['pro_foto1'];
    }
    else {
        switch ($row['pro_thema']) {
            case 'Vrede en Mensenrechten':
                $photo = '/afbeeldingen/vrede-en-mensenrechten.jpg';
                break;
            case 'Samenleven in Nederland':
                $photo = '/afbeeldingen/samenleven-in-nederland';
                break;
            // ... add as many entries as required
            default:
                // show default photo
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I read my row of data into an associative array $row? What I do now to get connected to the WP-Database where I made a new row "haella_projecten" is: global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM haella_projecten_test WHERE pro_status = 'normaal'");    
$thema = $r->pro_thema;

Comment: @Ullitasch please see my edit. That should fetch the results into an associative array for processing.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is giving the right output. Thank you for helping me find the right way:

```
     if(empty($r->pro_foto1)){
         if($r->pro_thema == "Geloof en Samenleving") {
             echo "/afbeeldingen/geloof-en-samenleving.jpg"; 
         }
         elseif($r->pro_thema == "Milieu en Duurzaamheid") {
             echo "/afbeeldingen/milieu-en-duurzaamheid.jpg"; 
         }
         elseif($r->pro_thema == "Samenleven in Nederland") {
             echo "/afbeeldingen/samenleven-in-nederland.jpg"; 
         }
         elseif($r->pro_thema == "Vrede en Mensenrechten") {
             echo "/afbeeldingen/vrede-en-mensenrechten.jpg"; 
         }
         elseif($r->pro_thema == "Overig") {
             echo "/afbeeldingen/overig.jpg"; 
         }
         elseif($r->pro_thema == "Kerstgift") {
             echo "/afbeeldingen/overig.jpg"; 
         }
         else {
             echo "/afbeeldingen/overig.jpg"; 
         }
     }
     else{
         echo "".$r->pro_foto1.""; 
     }
```